# Flashlight is not working in Barcode scanner program (Zxing)

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I use ZXing program for bar-code scanning the code scanning works well but flash light is not working  in the program any suggestion that will be helpful for me for further proceeding of the code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you check the "Use front light" setting in the barcode scanner? It doesn't work on all phones though.

Comment: Thanks Joubarc its working... I comment the "use front light" option

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
     CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        TimeSpan timespan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Device.StartTimer(timespan, () =>
        {
            if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return false;
            }

            scanner.Torch(true);

            return true;

        });

       scanner.Scan(Options);
```